# spring boot ssl shows not secure

Tags: spring-boot, ssl

I've applied my PKCS12 certificate to my gateway. 
My certificate is a wildcard certificate and i'm trying to apply it 
to the gateway so I don't have do this for all my micro-services.

These are the settings in my properties file for development:

```
server.port:8443
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store=integration.domain.net.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=*********
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-alias=integration.domain.net
```

The dev server starts up and SSL is enabled. When I open the connection to https://localhost:8080/ I am redirected to :8443 as I expect. However, the browser is indicating the connection is 'Not Secure'.

I can see that my certificate is being used so I'm a bit confused as to why this is not working. I'd like to know how to resolve this so that our clients see that our gateway is properly secured.

Does anybody have any ideas or suggestions?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured this out. My certificate is obviously looking for a valid domain or subdomain that corresponds to the information contained therein. So of course, localhost is not there. I just added a dev-integration.domain.net to my /etc/hosts file for development and everything is just fine.

Sorry if I wasted anyone's time.